# App crashing during submission process

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, appstore-approval

I have an app and was ready to realease it the app store. Going through tutorials, (lynda) everything was going fine until I made some changes to 'Custom iOS Target Properties'

The app had been tested, warnings taken care of. Everything was functioning properly until I started all the code signing stuff. Now the app crashes as soon as the first screen loads. It simply goes black after the launch image goes away. Here are some things that I think might have a role:

During the code signing process, I inadvertently deleted a key in 'Custom iOS Target Properties'. Not sure which it was. No other significant changes except all the code signing processes.

Is there any way to restore the settings?

Has anyone experienced anything like this? What should I be looking for? Everything still builds properly. I am completely clueless on this issue. Can anyone offer a suggestion? thanks!

Comment: atleast include the warning in your question

Comment: There isn't one. the app simply goes black

Comment: iphone/ipad? storyboard? simulator/device test? debug?

Comment: it's an iphone app, built for ios7. it crashes in the simulator and on a physical device.

Comment: erm... breakpoint the first few `-viewDidLoad` methods and see where the flow hits a deadend. black screen and no crash log may be that the main `viewController` is not being called (_not sure but..._)

Comment: If you messed up your project settings beyond repair, you could always create a new project and just import your existing files into it.

Comment: I'm convinced it's not in the code, but rather the xcode project is somehow corrupted.

Comment: i am with you that it may not be the code but just asking. anyways... has the project been done using storyboard?

Comment: yes, it is using a storyboard. Even creating a new blank view controller and setting it as the initial scene produces the same result

Comment: ok, so in your `Custom iOS Target Properties`, check the `Main Storyboard file base name` key

Comment: So, I set breakpoints in my initial view controllers, and nothing even gets hit. It's as if the app doesn't even know that any of the application code exists

Comment: I'm not finding that key.

Comment: then you (_may_) need to add that. something like: [image link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Info-plist.png)

Comment: How would I go about adding that key? This is new ground for me... In my original post, i mentioned I inadvertently deleted a key. This could be the key. Could you post this as a possible answer, so I can giver credit?

Comment: @stackVoidMan It appears that this was the cause of the trouble. Can you post this as your answer? Thank you SO much!

Comment: yeah, that key is quite important :P great! it solved your issue. i will add an answer now ;) (_was just testing the waters before a definite solution_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Storyboard, make sure the `Main Storyboard file base name` key exists in your `info.plist`.
It's value is generally "**MainStoryboard**", sometimes simply "**Main**" or could even be any name that you had customized your Storyboard with.

If the key is deleted or contains an incorrect Storyboard name then the app doesn't get an entrypoint to your custom classes and it's as good as not having any `viewController` in your app.

If you need to add this key:

1. Go to `info.plist`
2. Click on the **`+`** (in root and not within any array)
3. Specify

   - **key:** `Main Storyboard file base name`
   - **type:** `String`
   - **value:** `MainStoryboard` (*or your custom Storyboard name you have used*)

something like:

[image: infoPlist]

Comment: Thanks again! This saved me much grief! Two lessons learned here: it's very easy to accidentally delete a key--xcode gives no warnings AND don't trust snapshots!

Comment: @FirecrackerFred : my pleasure :) (_btw, i don't even use snapshots, i prefer svn_)